# Transfer VM from inside (guest OS)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I need to clone VM and transfer it to another (dev) environment. But I don't have access to hypervisor. 
Do you know of software (trial/free) or algorithm for the task?

I'm thinking the steps are like those:

1. Create images of all VM's drives from inside guest OS (`Windows Server 2003/2008R2`) with `XXX` software.
2. Create new VM in another environment (different AD forest)
3. Create drives of the same size.
4. Restore data from images into those drives.
5. ?? Somehow change AD domain of accounts for services (IIS, SQL Server) to work or recreate and reassign account with respect of new domain ??

Will it works? Or any other simplier way of solving this (one-time) task?

Answer (score 2):

Run Disk2Vhd inside the VM. It uses the volume snapshot capabilities of Windows to make a copy of the hard drive and write it to a VHD. From there, you are free to use that VHD on your new VM, or convert as needed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx

When you first boot up the VM, do not allow it to access the network. Change the domain membership to workgroup. This will erase the domain credentials for the computer from the computer itself, but not remove the computer from AD. If you leave it connected to the network while you do this, then your original VM will have its computer account deleted, which I don't think you want.

Then you can connect it to the network and join it to the new AD domain, and then change the service accounts and permissions to the accounts in the new AD domain.

Answer (score 1):

VMware allows to create VM images from physical machines - you could try to create an image from a the VM and then move it to another physical server. I've never tried to use it with with virtual machines, so I'm not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try.

It works with VMware ESx hyper-visor, but usually it's easy to convert a VM image to another type (e.g. VMware image to VirtualBox image).

Here's the link: https://www.vmware.com/pl/products/converter